# StopPress chat not working for me

Tags: bug

StopPress, why you no work?

[image]

Been a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens since day one for me. Sometimes I have to try four different browsers to get it working. Even when I clearly see that I'm logged in, I get asked to log in. Then there're cases where it logs in automatically, refreshes the page, but doesn't let me post. Blablabla... guess this won't change. :/